# dataframe error when comparing expression levels: TypeError: Unordered Categoricals can only compare equality or not

Tags: python, pandas, scanpy

I am working with an anndata object gleaned from analyzing single-cell RNAseq data using scanpy to obtain clusters. This is far along in the process (near completed) and I am now trying to obtain a list of the average expression of certain marker genes in the leiden clusters from my data. I am getting an error at the following point.

```
# Backbone imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from pathlib import Path
# Single Cell imports
import anndata
import scanpy as sc

markers = ["MS4A1", "CD72", "CD37", "CD79A", "CD79B","CD19"]
grouping_column = "leiden"
df = sc.get.obs_df(hy_bc, markers + [grouping_column])
mean_expression = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin([grouping_column])].mean(axis=0)
```

mean_expression:

```
MS4A1    1.594015
CD72     0.421510
CD37     1.858241
CD79A    1.801162
CD79B    1.180483
CD19     0.430246
dtype: float32

df, mean_expression = df.align(mean_expression, axis=1, copy=False)
```

[image: df,mean expression results]

***Error happens here***

```
g = (df > mean_expression).groupby(grouping_column)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [88], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 g = (df > mean_expression).groupby(grouping_column)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JHH216-hT246\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py:70, in _unpack_zerodim_and_defer.<locals>.new_method(self, other)
     66             return NotImplemented
     68 other = item_from_zerodim(other)
---> 70 return method(self, other)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JHH216-hT246\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py:56, in OpsMixin.__gt__(self, other)
     54 @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__gt__")
     55 def __gt__(self, other):
---> 56     return self._cmp_method(other, operator.gt)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JHH216-hT246\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:6934, in DataFrame._cmp_method(self, other, op)
   6931 self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=False, level=None)
   6933 # See GH#4537 for discussion of scalar op behavior
-> 6934 new_data = self._dispatch_frame_op(other, op, axis=axis)
   6935 return self._construct_result(new_data)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JHH216-hT246\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:6985, in DataFrame._dispatch_frame_op(self, right, func, axis)
   6979     # TODO: The previous assertion `assert right._indexed_same(self)`
   6980     #  fails in cases with empty columns reached via
   6981     #  _frame_arith_method_with_reindex
   6982 
   6983     # TODO operate_blockwise expects a manager of the same type
   6984     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 6985         bm = self._mgr.operate_blockwise(
   6986             # error: Argument 1 to "operate_blockwise" of "ArrayManager" has
   6987             # incompatible type "Union[ArrayManager, BlockManager]"; expected
   6988             # "ArrayManager"
   6989             # error: Argument 1 to "operate_blockwise" of "BlockManager" has
   6990             # incompatible type "Union[ArrayManager, BlockManager]"; expected
   6991             # "BlockManager"
   6992             right._mgr,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   6993             array_op,
   6994         )
   6995     return self._constructor(bm)
   6997 elif isinstance(right, Series) and axis == 1:
   6998     # axis=1 means we want to operate row-by-row

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JHH216-hT246\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:1409, in BlockManager.operate_blockwise(self, other, array_op)
   1405 def operate_blockwise(self, other: BlockManager, array_op) -> BlockManager:
   1406     """
   1407     Apply array_op blockwise with another (aligned) BlockManager.
   1408     """
-> 1409     return operate_blockwise(self, other, array_op)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JHH216-hT246\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\ops.py:63, in operate_blockwise(left, right, array_op)
     61 res_blks: list[Block] = []
     62 for lvals, rvals, locs, left_ea, right_ea, rblk in _iter_block_pairs(left, right):
---> 63     res_values = array_op(lvals, rvals)
     64     if left_ea and not right_ea and hasattr(res_values, "reshape"):
     65         res_values = res_values.reshape(1, -1)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JHH216-hT246\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:269, in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    260         raise ValueError(
    261             "Lengths must match to compare", lvalues.shape, rvalues.shape
    262         )
    264 if should_extension_dispatch(lvalues, rvalues) or (
    265     (isinstance(rvalues, (Timedelta, BaseOffset, Timestamp)) or right is NaT)
    266     and not is_object_dtype(lvalues.dtype)
    267 ):
    268     # Call the method on lvalues
--> 269     res_values = op(lvalues, rvalues)
    271 elif is_scalar(rvalues) and isna(rvalues):  # TODO: but not pd.NA?
    272     # numpy does not like comparisons vs None
    273     if op is operator.ne:

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JHH216-hT246\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py:70, in _unpack_zerodim_and_defer.<locals>.new_method(self, other)
     66             return NotImplemented
     68 other = item_from_zerodim(other)
---> 70 return method(self, other)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JHH216-hT246\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py:141, in _cat_compare_op.<locals>.func(self, other)
    139 if not self.ordered:
    140     if opname in ["__lt__", "__gt__", "__le__", "__ge__"]:
--> 141         raise TypeError(
    142             "Unordered Categoricals can only compare equality or not"
    143         )
    144 if isinstance(other, Categorical):
    145     # Two Categoricals can only be compared if the categories are
    146     # the same (maybe up to ordering, depending on ordered)
    148     msg = "Categoricals can only be compared if 'categories' are the same."

TypeError: Unordered Categoricals can only compare equality or not
```

Code I have, but have not run yet because of the error:

```
frac = lambda z: sum(z) / z.shape[0]
frac.__name__ = "pos_frac"
g.aggregate([sum, frac])
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `grouping column` is a categorical column and not `float` or `int`. try adding this line after the instantiation of the dataframe.

```
df = sc.get.obs_df(hy_bc, markers + [grouping_column])
df[grouping_column] = df[grouping_column].astype('int64')
```

another issue I noticed. the expression `df > mean_expression` will produce all false values in `leiden` because `leiden` has the value `NaN` in the mean expression. therefore when you use `groupby`, you will only have one group which is the value `False`. One group defeats the purpose of `groupby`. Not sure what are you trying to do but wanted to point that out.